# How can I store data retrieved from two tables into another table in java / servlet / jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have these three tables:

- `users`: stores the details of the users registered to my site.
- `events`: stores the details of the events that are held on the Technovision festival.
- `registered_users`: stores the details of users registered for an event.

When somebody clicks on the "register" button, it should pass the parameter `user_id` to the servlet named `RegisterServlet` via link (anchor tag).

And in `RegisterServlet` I want to retrieve data from `users` table and `events` table so that I can store combined columns of data into `registered_users` table.

I have tried doing that, but failing in some part which is hard to figure out.

If anyone can help me in this scenario that would be great.

```
 <a href="/RegisterEvent?id=<%=Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("event_id")) %>">Register</a>
```

Above is the code(button where user clicks) I used in JSP to pass `event_id` to the servlet using link tag.

***RegisterServlet.java***

```
package com.event;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

public class RegisterEvent extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        int i1;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String username = (String) session.getAttribute("uname");

        String event_id = request.getParameter("id");

        String fname, lname, email, colgname, event_name;
        int contact;

        try {

            //loading drivers for mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //creating connection with the database 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/technovision", "root", "root");

            String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?";

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

            ps.setString(1, username);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                fname = rs.getString("fname");
                lname = rs.getString("lname");
                email = rs.getString("emailid");
                contact = rs.getInt("mobile");
                colgname = rs.getString("colgname");
            }

            String sql2 = "SELECT event_name FROM events WHERE event_id=?";

            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);

            ps1.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(event_id));

            ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();

            while (rs1.next()) {
                event_name = rs1.getString("event_name");
            }

            String sql3 = "INSERT INTO registered_users(`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`contact`,`college_name`,`event_name`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);

            ps3.setString(1, fname);
            ps3.setString(2, lname);
            ps3.setString(3, email);
            ps3.setInt(4, contact);
            ps3.setString(5, colgname);
            ps3.setString(6, event_name);

            i1 = ps3.executeUpdate();

            if (i1 > 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("register-success.jsp");
            }

        } catch (Exception se) {
            System.out.println(se);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What happen with this code, not work with you, or what?

Comment: yes its not working, showing error at "fname" may not have been initialized, i guess my sql1 query is not running

Comment: Don't you think that is pertinent information that you should have included in your question? BTW: This is really basic Java knowledge: if you initialize a variable only in a `while`-loop, `if`-statement or anything else that is conditionally executed, then the compiler will give you an error that the variable might not have been initialised. In this case it also indicates that you forget the exception use-case where the user does not exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you don't inislase your attribute so you should to use this :

```
String fname = "", lname = "", email = "", colgname = "", event_name = "";
```

Instead to this :

```
String fname, lname, email, colgname, event_name;
```

Because you use them in your `while(){...}` so you should to init them

Comment: I tried the solution you gave me, it executed successfully, but my `registered_users` table stored only the event_name , rest all details remain unfetched from users table. i guess i should make use of `user_id` as my primary key, i haven't added that column thinking that my `username` is unique and can act as a primary key.

Comment: ok @raviloop go ahead and let me know what you get, your problem that you ask is solved this is a new problem :)

Comment: nope i'm unable to solve that problem, now my servlet `RegisterEvent` is not getting called when clicked on `register` button(link), i can't figure out why